# Prime number(Python 3)

Tags: python, break, continue

My goal is to build a programm, that says is a number prime or not.
A positive whole number n > 2 is prime if no number between 2 and sqrt(n)
divides n.

Here is my code:

```
import math

def main():
     print("Prime number or not")
     try:
          N = -1
          while N<2:
              print("Error!Enter numbers greater than two")
              N = int(input("Enter the right number:"))
              values = list(range(2,round(math.sqrt(N))))
              for i in values:
                  if i%N !=0:
                      continue
                  x = print("The number is not prime")
                 elif i%N ==0:
                     break
                 x = print("The number is NOT prime")
           print(x)

    except ValueError:
        print("Error!Print correct number")
    except NameError:
        print("Error!Print the numbers")

main()
```

But is shows a syntax error in line

```
elif i%N ==0:
```

Please, give me some advice how to correct this error and about the code in general. I am new in learning Python, so any help and critic will be good!
Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation is confused. Can you please re-indent your code, preferably with four spaces?

Comment: You've got serious indentation problems

Comment: The `elif` is not connected to the `if` block above it. You can't put other statements between these blocks.

Comment: Where did you learn to use eval on input?

Comment: In Python, indentation is part of syntax. Please fix it and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Seeing `eval(x)` to convert a number makes me sad. Use `int(x)`instead!

Comment: Is it better?Sorry for previous indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted this to be your whole programme, here is my solution:

```
# Get num
num = input('Input a whole number: ')

# Is num valid
try:
  num = int(num)
  if num < 1 or num > 1000000000000:
    print('Your field cannot be greater than one quantillion or less than one.')
  else:
    # Is num 2 or 5, if yes, prime.
    if num != 2 and num != 5:
      # Is the last number of num 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8, if yes, composite.
      lastNum = str(num)[-1]
      if lastNum == '0' or lastNum == '2' or lastNum == '4' or lastNum == '5' or lastNum == '6' or lastNum == '8':
        print('Your number is composite.')
        if lastNum == '5':
          print(str(num) + ' is divisible by 5.')
        else:
          print(str(num) + ' is divisible by 2.')
      else:
        # List multiples of 3 less than 123, call it multiplesOf3.
        multiplesOf3 = []
        appendMultiple = 0
        for i in range(40):
          appendMultiple += 3
          multiplesOf3.append(appendMultiple)
        # Get sum of all numbers in num, name is sumOfNum
        sumOfNum = 0
        numStr = str(num)
        for i in range(len(numStr)):
          sumOfNum += int(numStr[i])
        # Is sumOfNum in multiplesOf3? 
        numMultipleOf3 = sumOfNum in multiplesOf3
        if numMultipleOf3 == True:
          print('Your number is composite.\n' + str(num) + ' is divisible by 3.')
        else:
          print('Your number is prime.')
    else:
      print('Your number is prime') 
except:
  print('Your field needs to be a whole number. Make sure there is no decimal points (i.e. 12.0 will not be accepted).')
```

But if you wanted this to be just a function, here is my solution (Make sure you put in a parameter, it requires 1 argument; put in your number.)

```
 def isPrime(num): 
  try:
    num = int(num)
    if num < 1 or num > 1000000000000:
      print('Your field cannot be greater than one quantillion or less than one.')
    else:
      # Is num 2 or 5, if yes, prime.
      if num != 2 and num != 5:
        # Is the last number of num 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8, if yes, composite.
        lastNum = str(num)[-1]
        if lastNum == '0' or lastNum == '2' or lastNum == '4' or lastNum == '5' or lastNum == '6' or lastNum == '8':
          print('Your number is composite.')
          if lastNum == '5':
            print(str(num) + ' is divisible by 5.')
          else:
            print(str(num) + ' is divisible by 2.')
        else:
          # List multiples of 3 less than 123, call it multiplesOf3.
          multiplesOf3 = []
          appendMultiple = 0
          for i in range(40):
            appendMultiple += 3
            multiplesOf3.append(appendMultiple)
          # Get sum of all numbers in num, name is sumOfNum
          sumOfNum = 0
          numStr = str(num)
          for i in range(len(numStr)):
            sumOfNum += int(numStr[i])
          # Is sumOfNum in multiplesOf3? 
          numMultipleOf3 = sumOfNum in multiplesOf3
          if numMultipleOf3 == True:
            print('Your number is composite.\n' + str(num) + ' is divisible by 3.')
          else:
            print('Your number is prime.')
      else:
        print('Your number is prime') 
  except:
    print('Your field needs to be a whole number. Make sure there is no decimal points (i.e. 12.0 will not be accepted).')
```

Another way,

```
def isprime(n):
  if min(n//2,n//3,n//5) == 1:
    return True
  elif min(n%2,n%3,n%5) == 0:
    return False
  return True
```

This is SO much shorter!

Answer (score -1):

assuming that the indentation on the question is correct NOW, the problem is that your `elif` block doesn't have an `if` parent. It's also indented wrong, which even if you fix the first error will throw an `IndentationError` but that's almost beside the point.

```
for i in values:
    if i%N !=0:
        continue
    x = print("The number is not prime")  # huh? you've left the `if` block
   elif i%N ==0:  # under-indented
       break
```